# convert base64 to image file using react native

Tags: react-native, react-redux, base64

i have problem to convert base 64 to image file i only have image base64 and i want to convert that to file because i want to post that file in form data i need to convert base64 to file i get base64 from this code and put base64 to the state

```
takePhotoFromLibrary = () => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        cropping: true,
        includeBase64: true
    }).then(image => {
        console.log(image);
        this.setState({ image: image.data });
        
        
    });
}
```

now i want to convert base64 to image file

Comment: react-native-image-picker will also return a local temp file uri in response (ImagePicker). so just change `image.data` with `image.uri`

Comment: are you think is that helping because my webserver get formdata and my formdata is file and it says image.uri is undefined